# HDD partition is read-only despite 'rw' flag in fstab

Tags: 18.04, ntfs, fstab, read-only

I have a problem with mounting my HDD.
I have Kubuntu 18.04 running on my SSD.
Also, I have Win10 on the HDD.  Now, I try to mount one of HDD partitions (not the one with Win10 system). But it mounts only as read-only, even though I have 'rw' parameter in fstab:

```
UUID=BAC6A307C6A2C34D /media/hdd1 ntfs-3g defaults,windows-names,locale=en_US.utf8,rw 0 0
```

I have also tried other configurations for fstab, but it is still read-only. That is what "mount -l" command tells me about the drive:

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/hdd1 type fuseblk (ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Could anybody help with this?

**Edit 1:**
The output of 'chkdsk' command under Windows:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  70144 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  111 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  30 reparse records processed.
  77888 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.

Errors found.  CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

It says, that it runs in read-only mode.
But, actually I can both read and write files on this disk under Windows.

**Solved:**
The problem was solved, when I turned off Windows' updates and shut it down. Check links from oldfred's comment.

Comment: Have you tried running `chkdsk` from windows? Was Windows fully shut down (not pseudo-hibernate-shutdown)?

Comment: @xiota, I did not, but I'll try today. Windows was shut down as usual.

Comment: Usual shutdown is with fast start up or hibernation. And then the Linux NTFS driver only mounts Read only. And Windows updates turn it back on, even if you turned it off before. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred If you or the OP could write an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that Windows uses hibernation by default. To turn it off, I used the [following procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/843338). Also, I turned off Windows' updates just in case (they can turn hibernation back on).

Thanks to oldfred for provided links.